# How to create an APEX_COLLECTION?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle12c

I want to create an apex_collection in the Oracle SQL Developer for my apex webapplication. 
Here's my code:

```
 apex_collections.create_or_truncate_collection('TEST');
```

After running the statement I get the following:

[image]

If I enter the select-statement:

```
SELECT *
  FROM apex_collections
 WHERE collection_name = 'TEST';
```

afterwards, I get this:

[image]

It seems to me that no collection has been created,although there is no error code. What am I doing wrong? Why is the collection not created? I also tried to run the statement in the SQL Workshop of Oracle APEX, but the command is unknown there. I am using Oracle 12c version.

Comment: apex_collections.create_or_truncate_collection() only has an input, not an output - what you're showing in the first picture I don't think is returned by the code you shared.

Comment: Yes you are right, but what I am showing in the first picture is what appears in the console after running the statement.

Answer (score 6):

You will need a valid APEX session to create the collection. If you are on APEX 18.1 or later, use the procedure `apex_session.create_session` (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.2/AEAPI/APEX_SESSION.htm#AEAPI-GUID-348C879F-3B45-4F4E-8641-518C711CE76F)) to create one. Make sure that the app_id is valid for the workspace that your schema is assigned to.

For anything before 18.1, OraOpenSource [oos-utils](https://github.com/OraOpenSource/oos-utils) has a procedure that does the same: `oos_util_apex.create_session` (see [code](https://github.com/OraOpenSource/oos-utils/blob/master/source/packages/oos_util_apex.pkb)). You will need to install oos-utils, or at least compile this package in your schema. Alternatively, replicate the activity contained in this procedure.

Update: Also, I just noticed Jeff Smith's comments. You will need to add members to the collection in order to get meaningful results.

```
begin
  apex_session.create_session(
    p_app_id => 100
    , p_page_id => 1
    , p_username => 'somebody'
  );
end;
/

select * from apex_collections; -- shows nothing

begin
  apex_collection.create_or_truncate_collection(
    p_collection_name => 'test'
  );

  apex_collection.add_member(
    p_collection_name => 'test'
    , p_c001 => 'test row'
  );
end;
/

select * from apex_collections; -- shows one record
```

Also, if you are using SQLDEV to troubleshoot the collections in an APEX session, then you'll want to use either the `apex_session.attach` or `oos_util_apex.join_session` procedure, depending on the version of APEX you are running. Use the APEX Session ID assigned to your browser session.
HTH.