# APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_COLLECTION is failing when executed externally

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

In `SQL Developer`, I am trying to debug a function which is using `APEX_COLLECTION` but getting `EXCEPTION_ORA_6501` on creating a collection.

This piece of code works fine when called from Oracle Apex but it is failing when executed externally.

Please help.

[image]

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE function test123 return number 
is
    coll_name varchar2(20) := 'mycollection123';
begin
    if APEX_COLLECTION.COLLECTION_EXISTS(p_collection_name => coll_name) then
        APEX_COLLECTION.DELETE_COLLECTION(p_collection_name => coll_name);
    End if;
    APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_COLLECTION(p_collection_name => coll_name);
    return 0;
end;
```

> Connecting to the database SYS AT XEPDB1. Executing PL/SQL: CALL
> DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '127.0.0.1', '23364' ) Debugger accepted
> connection from database on port 23364. Source breakpoint:
> TEST123.pls:7 Source breakpoint: TEST123.pls:8 Exception breakpoint:
> WWV_FLOW_COLLECTION_INT.pls:-1, $Oracle.EXCEPTION_ORA_6501,
> ORA-06501: PL/SQL: program error ORA-06512: at
> "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_COLLECTION_INT", line 99 ORA-06512: at
> "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_COLLECTION", line 53 ORA-06512: at
> "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_COLLECTION", line 365 ORA-06512: at
> "SYS.TEST123", line 8 ORA-06512: at line 5 Executing PL/SQL: CALL
> DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.DISCONNECT() Process exited. Disconnecting from the
> database SYS AT XEPDB1. Debugger disconnected from database.

Comment: You need an apex session to use apex_collection. It is built so that you can only access data owned by your session. So you need a session first.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52872838/how-to-create-an-apex-collection

Comment: @GregJarm Yes it worked. `COLLECTION_EXISTS` does not require session but `CREATE_COLLECTION` does. How can i use this `create_session` to debug a function inside a package? of course i won't add this call in the actual function.

Comment: One idea would be to run a procedure that attempts to use apex_session.attach. If this failed for expired session then stop. If it succeeds then you don't need to create a session. If it fails otherwise then create the new session.

Comment: You can do this in a separate procedure that you call since the session state ends up living in package state so you have global variables available.